# LaTeX Error: Unicode character

Tags: texlive, unicode, russian

I've changed my OS (yesterday and I'm new to it) to Ubuntu 22.04, installed TeX Live and can't understand why it's not working with *russian* and *ukrainian* languages. I'm using `Sublime Text` as an editor

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
 
Текст

\end{document}
```

**Errors:**

```
[Compiling /home/anmnv/Documents/text.tex]

TraditionalBuilder: Engine: pdflatex. Invoking latexmk... done.

Errors:

    /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty:111: Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `t2aenc.def' not found. [\ProcessOptions*]
    /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty:4254: Package babel Error: Unknown option 'russian'. Either you misspelled it [\ProcessOptions*]
    /home/anmnv/Documents/text.tex:8: LaTeX Error: Unicode character Т (U+0422) [Т]
    /home/anmnv/Documents/text.tex:8: LaTeX Error: Unicode character е (U+0435) [Те]
    /home/anmnv/Documents/text.tex:8: LaTeX Error: Unicode character к (U+043A) [Тек]
    /home/anmnv/Documents/text.tex:8: LaTeX Error: Unicode character с (U+0441) [Текс]
    /home/anmnv/Documents/text.tex:8: LaTeX Error: Unicode character т (U+0442) [Текст]
    
    No warnings.
    
    /home/anmnv/Documents/text.log:1: Double-click here to open the full log.
    
    [Done!]
```

Comment: Works here for me if I switch `T2A,T1` to `T1, T2A`. Strange...

Comment: Get rid of `fontenc` and `inputenc` and recompile with (preferably) LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Rmano still the same problem

Comment: @Ingmar Your suggestion gives:
Errors:

/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty:4254: Package babel Error: Unknown option 'russian'. Either you misspelled it [\ProcessOptions*]

Comment: You'll also need a font that supports Russian glyphs. See my answer below for a full working example.

Comment: You are using the debian packaged texlive, so need to install babel russian via apt or whatever linux package manager you use, as apparently you chose not to install all texlive packages originally

Comment: @DavidCarlisle nice idea I'll try

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/sid/texlive-lang-cyrillic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DavidCarlisle suggestion "*I had to install babel russian*" and also thanks to @Rmano suggestion about "switch `T2A,T1` to `T1, T2A`" (it really works).
So my solution is:

> sudo aptitude -y install texlive-lang-cyrillic

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
 
Текст

\end{document}
```

Comment: I still suggest you get rid of `inputenc` … utf-8 has been the default for years now. (And Sublime certainly supports it.)

Comment: Yes, It works without You are right

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on TL 2022 (Windows 10, but still):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{cmunrm.otf}

\begin{document}
 
Hello, world! Привет, мир!

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have the babel russian support insalled, the OP has not, so switching to luatex will still error.

Comment: Fair enough. But isn't the point of TL that it comes with everything pre-installed, so to speak? I usually don't do Russian, but it worked out of the box for me.

Comment: @Ingmar still many errors, like ```Package fontspec Error: The font "NotoSans" cannot be found. []``` and ```/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty:3901: Font \TU/lmr/bx/n/10=[lmroman10-bold]:+tlig; at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad. [\strongfontdeclare{ \bfseries }] ```

Comment: Yes, you might have to install a suitable font as well. I chose Noto because it's common and free. I have changed my example to use a suitable font that comes pre-installed.

Comment: @Ingmar no. doing a full install of all packages is an install time option.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question as it will certainly always give the same error `Package babel Error: Unknown option 'russian'. `  (other font related errors may chage switching to luatex, but not that) (A system on which this luatex document works would not have the issue shown in the original pdftex document)

Comment: Actually, I have removed that as well. Not required for a minimal example. (Even though he'll probably want to install it.)

Comment: @Ingmar OK but that's cheating:-)